# How do you convert a JSON object to a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON string that I would like to convert to a javascript array.  How can I do this?

I was under the impression thot JQuery could do this

Comment: It's not going to be possible to answer this definitively without seeing the string itself.

Comment: are you saying that it is not possible to parse all properly formatted JSON strings to a Javascript array? (or do you mean that some JSON strings are objects, and not convertable to an array?)

Comment: A JSON expression can be an object or an array.  If it's an object, like `{ "x": "y" }`, how exactly do you want to "convert" that to an array?  You can *parse* it, and then store the object in an array if you want to, I guess, but without more explanation it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general you can do `JSON.parse(jsonString)`.  Most browsers support this.

with jquery, if you tell `$.ajax()` that the response type is json, it will do this for you.  See the 'dataType' option here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 4):

[json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) is the usual choice for this. It has decent error checking and will use native browser decoding if available.